# Display Any Field fromAdmin Panel in Frontend via Shortcode?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, admin, dashboard, front-end

Frontend Admin by DynamiApps allows you to display/embed any ACF field in frontend.

What is the best process to replicate this concept to display any field from any admin page in front end? i.e, We don't want to be limited specifically to ACF fields. Basically, user can choose any field from any admin panel page and display that field frontend via shortcode.

Is it possible to achieve something like this?

Thanks